# Mysql database design recommendation

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need recommendation.

I want to see similar things by slash(/),
like A/B/C.

If I have a table Sample_Table:

```
Sample_Table
-------------
1- A - 10
2- B - 20
3- C - 30
4- D - 50
```

What I want to achieve is ,
mark A,B,C are similar.

And show in view(backend is php) like

```
First row A/B/C
Second row D
```

One solution that comes into my mind is to use another column and 
insert the same reference to A,B,C . Like the following :

```
Sample_Table
-------------
1- A - 10 - A1
2- B - 20 - A1
3- C - 30 - A1
4- D - 50 - null
```

Is it okay for future enhancement if needed ?
May be we need to add more feature /complex calculation later.
Any suggestion please?

N.B User will input which are similar , using this input i have to work.
They can mark A,B,C similar or A,C,D similar or any possible combination.

Comment: In what way are a,b,c similar?

Comment: A,B,C are of similar type . User will mark/input that . They can mark A,B,C,D  all are similar or A,C,D similar . Any combination is possible.

Comment: Well if ___similarity___ is based on user knowledge then you will have to add a column to contain that knowledge. Or better still add a `similarity` table to link the similiar record

Comment: Ok. So I will enter the data into another table and save the reference to my main table?? right

Comment: A separate table sounds more reasonable if every item could be similar to many other items.For example where a is similar to b,c,d but b,c is not similar to d. You have to work through a large range of scenarios to work out a design that is best for you bearing in mind how you intend to use the data,